# polymorphism, visitor, how to call overloaded function?

Tags: c++, visitor-pattern

I want to make subclassed object which will react differently with other subclassing objects (class can welcome another class but not all)
The principle of the code is derivative from the visitor design pattern:

```
class A
{
public :
    virtual bool isWelcoming(const A* other) const =0;
    virtual bool isWelcomable(const A* other) const =0;

};

class C;

class B: public A
{
public:

    virtual bool isWelcoming(const A* other) const 
    {
        return other->isWelcomable(this);
    }

    bool isWelcomable(const A* other) const 
    {
        return false;
    }

    bool isWelcomable(const B* other) const 
    {
        return true;
    }

    bool isWelcomable(const C* other) const 
    {
        return false;
    }

};

class C: public A
{
public:

    virtual bool isWelcoming(const A* other) const 
    {
        return other->isWelcomable(this);
    }

    bool isWelcomable(const A* other) const 
    {
        return false;
    }

    bool isWelcomable(const B* other) const 
    {
        return true;
    }

    bool isWelcomable(const C* other) const 
    {
        return true;
    }
};
```

But when I do this

```
A *b1=new B;
A *b2=new B;
A *c=new C;

std::cout<<b1->isWelcoming(b2); //--> return false but I want true;
std::cout<<c->isWelcoming(b1); //--> return false OK;
std::cout<<b1->isWelcoming(c); //--> return false but I want true;
```

It is always the function isWelcomable(const A* other) that is called and not the overload function isWelcomable(const B* other) or isWelcomable(const C* other).

It is normal because A::isWelcomable(const B* other) and A::isWelcomable(const C* other) don't exist ... and I don't want they exist.

Is there a way to call the isWelcomable(const B* other) or the isWelcomable(const C* other) function?

With dynamic_cast but it is not very clean ? like this :

```
class C;    
class B: public A
    {
public:

    virtual bool isWelcoming(const A* other) const 
    {
        return other->isWelcomable(this);
    }

    bool isWelcomable(const A* other) const 
    {
        const B* b=dynamic_cast<B*>(A);
        if (b)
            return isWelcomable(b);

        const C* c=dynamic_cast<C*>(A);
        if (c)
            return isWelcomable(c);

        return false;
    }

    bool isWelcomable(const B* other) const 
    {
        return true;
    }

    bool isWelcomable(const C* other) const 
    {
        return false;
    }

};

class C: public A
{
public:

    virtual bool isWelcoming(const A* other) const 
    {
        return other->isWelcomable(this);
    }

    bool isWelcomable(const A* other) const 
    {
        const B* b=dynamic_cast<B*>(A);
        if (b)
            return isWelcomable(b);

        const C* c=dynamic_cast<C*>(A);
        if (c)
            return isWelcomable(c);

        return false;
    }

    bool isWelcomable(const B* other) const 
    {
        return true;
    }

    bool isWelcomable(const C* other) const 
    {
        return true;
    }
};
```

Thanks for your help.

***UPDATE :***
The solution with dynamic_cast, that looks a bit like the Acyclic visitor (thanks to TavianBarnes) can do what I want but uses the not recommended dynamic_cast. Furthermore, this solution violate the Liskov Substitution Principle.

I have thought to use getType() like Kai Guther suggest, with string instead an enum, but this solution violate too the Liskov Substitution Principle, and, in my opinion, more than the "dynamic_cast" solution.

So, I don't think there are solution that don't violate this principle, and I will choose the first solution because I find it more elegant, the function doesn't have to be fast (only one operation responding to a user action) and the application is not destined for an embedded system.

Comment: Didn't look too much into the code as this isn't a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but aren't you just missing `return` in `B::isWelcoming()` function?

Comment: It compiles from scratch by inserting 2 missing ";" and a missed return. Perfect! So it was easy to go into it with a debugger, see that the virtual declaration is missing for 2 overloads and everythings is fine! It is definitely a mcve!

Comment: Look into the Acyclic Visitor Pattern

Comment: @TavianBarnes : it looks like my solution with dynamic_cast, no?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you mix up *overloading* and *overriding*.

in the `B` class you have three *overloads* of the `isWelcomable` function, but only *one* of them overrides the `A::isWelcomable` function:

```
bool isWelcomable(const A* other) const;
```

And that is the function that will be called by `other->isWelcomable(this)`.

I suggest you make it a habit to use the `override` special keyword when working with polymorphism, to make sure that the function you define really overrides the parent class functions:

```
bool isWelcomable(const A* other) const override;  // Correct

bool isWelcomable(const B* other) const override;  // Incorrect, compiler error
```

---

And as mentioned, the `B::isWelcoming` function doesn't return anything even though it is declared to do so. That will of course lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which really makes all speculation about behavior moot.

Answer (score 0):

There are some typos: Missing ';' at end of classes.

Then you missed that the overloads of `virtual bool isWelcomable(const A* other) const =0;` for types `B*` and `C*` are missing.

Then you missed to return the values from the function you call: `return other->isWelcomable(this);`

And why you have defined `virtual bool isWelcoming(const A* other) const` as virtual? There is no need for that!

General hints: Use `override` if you want to override a virtual function. In your case the compiler emits an error if you use it!

Always enable all warnings. The missing return statement is then catched before wondering of runtime results.

complete fixed code:

```
class A;
class B;    
class C;    

class A
{
    public : 
        virtual bool isWelcoming(const A* other) const =0;
        virtual bool isWelcomable(const A* other) const =0;
        virtual bool isWelcomable(const B* other) const =0;
        virtual bool isWelcomable(const C* other) const =0; 
};

class B: public A
{           
    public:

        bool isWelcoming(const A* other) const { return other->isWelcomable(this); }

        bool isWelcomable(const A* other) const override { return false; }
        bool isWelcomable(const B* other) const override { return true; }
        bool isWelcomable(const C* other) const override { return false; }
};

class C: public A
{       
    public:

        bool isWelcoming(const A* other) const { return other->isWelcomable(this); }

        bool isWelcomable(const A* other) const override { return false; }
        bool isWelcomable(const B* other) const override { return true; }
        bool isWelcomable(const C* other) const override { return true; }
};

int main()
{
    A *b1=new B;
    A *b2=new B;
    A *c=new C;

    std::cout<< b1->isWelcoming(b2); //--> return false but I want true;
    std::cout<< c ->isWelcoming(b1); //--> return false OK;
    std::cout<< b1->isWelcoming(c); //--> return false but I want true;
}
```

Comment: I don't want that the class B or the C figure in the class A. Otherwise I have edited my code.

Comment: @vcloarec: If you don't want that, you can't get your code working. If the overload for B and C are not defined, the `this` pointer will be converted to the base pointer which is A*. And then the method is called for A*. And then you get the result you already see.

Comment: that's why I am searching for a solution, an the only one i found it is using dynamic_cast like i have wrote in my question.

Comment: @vcloarec: Sounds like a XY problem. Why I programmer don't want the correct solution? dynamic_cast needs RTTI and RTTI is expensive in general. Especially for embedded systems it is typically switched off or can't be used at all. ( See avr target on gcc for example ). Having virtual dispatching is quite fine and fast. So why you won't something more complicated?

Comment: I have many class B or C, so i don't want to implement all of them in the class A. That's why i want the subclass manage themself.

Answer (score 0):

The base class pointer you pass to `isWelcoming` cannot be used to call the functions

```
 bool isWelcomable(const B* other) const;
 bool isWelcomable(const C* other) const;
```

As `A` does not have members with that signature. While you can replace the return type of a virtual function with the derived type, this does not work for the arguments.

To get the desired behavior, `A` needs a member function `isWelcomable` for each derived type

```
class A{
public :
  virtual bool isWelcoming(const A* other) const =0;
  virtual bool isWelcomable(const A* other) const =0;
  virtual bool isWelcomable(const B* other) const =0;
  virtual bool isWelcomable(const C* other) const =0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you do not want `A` to refer to the derived classes, you could also trade the `isWelcomable` function for a `getType` function

```
// enum for convenience
enum AType{a,b,c};                                                                             

class A{                                                                                                                                                                                      
public :                                                                                       
  virtual bool isWelcoming(const A* other) const =0; 
  // tell which derived type you are                                          
  virtual AType getType() const {return a;};                                                    
};                                                                                             

class B: public A{                                                                                                                                                                       
public:                                                                                      

  virtual bool isWelcoming(const A* other) const                                             
  {                                 
    // decide based on what type other points to                                                         
    switch(other->getType()){                                                                
    case(a):                                                                                 
      return false;                                                                          
    case(b):                                                                                 
      return true;                                                                           
    case(c):                                                                                 
      return true;                                                                           
    }                                                                                        
  }                                                                                          

  AType getType() const {return b;}                                                          
};                                                                                           

class C: public A{                                                                                                                                                                   
public:                                       

  virtual bool isWelcoming(const A* other) const
  {                                                                                                                             
    switch(other->getType()){                                                              
    case(a):                                                                               
      return false;                                                                        
    case(b):                                                                               
      return false;                                                                        
    case(c):                                                                               
      return true;                                                                         
    }                                                                                      
  }                                                                                        

  AType getType() const {return c;}                                                        
};
```

Note that this moves the information about whether `B` welcomes `C` and so on from the guest to the host, so `B` now has to know what it welcomes instead of who welcomes it.

Its also not a very elegant solution, essentially the list of derived classes was now moved from `A` to `AType`. As each derived class needs to be able to react to each other derived class depending on the type, there is no solution to this without having such a list somewhere.

Comment: I don't want that the class B or the class C figure in the class A.

Comment: Yes, it is not really nice design, you could make a virtual member function that returns some enum (encoding the type) and make the output of `isWelcoming` depending on the call to that function.